# Read a string from a text file and copy it on another text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

What I want to do is basically read a text file containing ping results, detect a certain string and copy it in another text file. the strings I want to copy are those bold in the example.

> Envoi d'une requˆte 'ping' sur star.c10r.facebook.com [31.13.81.17]
>   avec 32 octets de donn‚esÿ: 
>   R‚ponse de 31.13.81.17ÿ: **octets=32 temps=77 ms TTL=240**
>
> Statistiques Ping pour 31.13.81.17:
>       Paquetsÿ: envoy‚s = 1, re‡us = 1, perdus = 0 (perte 0%), 
>   Dur‚e approximative des boucles en millisecondes :
>       Minimum = 77ms, Maximum = 77ms, Moyenne = 77ms

I tried to execute this program but the variable "resultat" does't appear in the result.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%

for /f %%i in (testservers.txt) do (
  set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP') do (
       if %%a==R,ponse set resultat="%%b %%c %%d"
        )

   echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!] is resultat >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
)
```

Thank you.

Thanks to @Matt's help, I could edit my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt

for /f %%i in (testservers.txt) do (
  if not exist %OUTPUT_FILE% type NUL>%OUTPUT_FILE%
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^| find "TTL="') do (
   if errorlevel 0  set resultat=UP: %%a 
  )

  echo %%i is !resultat! >> %OUTPUT_FILE%
  set resultat=DOWN
)
```

I set the default value of "resultat" to DOWN, because I noticed that it will only change if "TTL" is found, that means the server is UP. If it is not found the program would display the default value of "resultat" which is DOWN.
The section "**octets=32 temps=77 ms TTL=240**" would only be displayed id the server is UP to show the stats. the result is something like this:

> www.google.com is UP:  octets=32 temps=470 ms TTL=42
>
> www.facebook.com is UP:  octets=32 temps=326 ms TTL=241
>   192.168.1.15 is UP:  octets=32 temps<1ms TTL=128
>   10.21.107.90 is Down

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why this `^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP` and that `!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!`  ? Both without impact.

Comment: @Endoro I deleted those two part, because they are in fact without impact. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems here. You're not actually checking the return of your ping to see if it worked before you say SERVER_IS_UP. You're not using the SERVER_ADDRESS variable correctly and you're not calling resultant as a variable.

See if this fixes it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=result.txt

for /f %%i in (testservers.txt) do (
  if not exist %OUTPUT_FILE% type NUL>%OUTPUT_FILE%
  set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^| find "TTL="') do (
   if errorlevel 0 echo %%1 is up && set resultat=%%a
   if errorlevel 1 echo %%i is down && set resultat=%%a is down
  )

  echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS!::=] is !resultat! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
  set resultat=
```

)

Comment: Thank you @Matt, your answer helped me a lot in doing what I wanted to. There are some points I want to add about the program you proposed:
- For the variable "resultat", it should be reset at each iteration after displaying it, because if the condition is not verified the program will display the last value "resultat" had. 
- I tried to display "Server is Down" in the case errorlevel is not 0 but it won't work, I don't really know why. Here is what I tried: "if errorlevel 0 (echo %%i is UP: %%a >>%OUTPUT_FILE% ) else (echo %%i is DOWN: %%a>> %OUTPUT_FILE%)"

Comment: Thank you @Matt. I edited to code, I wrote it in the question section. Your remarks were very helpful.